# How to Update values of a sparse matrix in Armadillo

Tags: sparse-matrix, armadillo

I am solving a Fluid Problem in which very large Sparse Matrix forms. In the context of Armadillo Sparse Matrix, I have a fixed `umat locations` matrix of storing indices and a variable `vec values` for each location. I have created a Sparse Matrix with Armadillo as `sp_mat A(locations, values)` before iteration starts. In each iteration I need solve for different `values`, `locations` remains same, and I wish update values in `A`.

Is there any way by which I can update `values` in `A`, replacing older ones with `batch insertion`, or any similar, methods provided in Armadillo? If no, then what is the best method, in the context of Speed, to do so?

Element Access, `A(i,j)`, is possible but due to large size it slow down the process. Batch Insertion seems faster and manageable.

Thanks a LOT !!

Answer (score 0):

Using C++11 / C++14, you can use the [batch insertion constructors](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat) in conjunction with [std::move()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/move/). For example:

```
sp_mat X;

X = std::move( sp_mat(locations, values) );
```

To enable C++11 mode in *gcc* or *clang*, compile with the `-std=c++11` option.